# Double spacing in chapter heading on some front matter pages

Tags: header-footer, templates, thesis, fncychap

I am using the Masters template from [latextemplates.com](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis) and have made some modifications to it for writing in a humanities style.

I have noticed though in the front matter that the chapter heading of my abbreviations page appears to have wider spacing around the text than other front matter page headings such as contents or list of figures. I think this has something to do with the fact the page uses a table(could be completely wrong about that!). As noted below template has its own .cls and I have looked at that but have not been able to find any solution.

I have a rough mwe that should highlight the issue. Unfortunately you with have to use the Thesis.cls that is part of the template to compile. I tried to recreate the problem in the article class or by bringing in the .cls into the mwe but am bit of a newbie and was getting too many errors. If I need to edit my MWE in any way please let me know.

I am looking for a solution to have the header on the abbreviations page the same as the other page in my mwe.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{Thesis}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}% Removes space above \chapter head
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}% Removes space above \chapter* head
\makeatother
\usepackage [UKenglish,american,british]{babel} %‘‘american’’ goes last, as main option.
\usepackage [babel=once,english=british]{csquotes} %Sets quote style once for whole document
%American quote style
\usepackage[notes, backend=biber, bookpages=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\begin{document}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LIST OF FIGURES/TABLES PAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\pagestyle{fancy} % The page style headers have been "empty" all this time, now use the "fancy" headers as defined before to bring them back

\lhead{\emph{List of Figures}} % Set the left side page header to "List of Figures"
\listoffigures % Write out the List of Figures

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABBREVIATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\clearpage % Start a new page

\lhead{\emph{Abbreviations}} % Set the left side page header to "Abbreviations"

\setstretch{1.5} % Set the line spacing to 1.5, this makes the following tables easier to read

\listofsymbols{ll} % Include a list of Abbreviations (a table of two columns)
{
%\textbf{Acronym} & \textbf{W}hat (it) \textbf{S}tands \textbf{F}or \\
\textbf{UN} & \textbf{U}nited \textbf{N}ations \\ 
\textbf{UK} & The \textbf{U}nited \textbf{K}ingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland\\
\textbf{US} & The \textbf{U}nited \textbf{S}tates of America\\
}

\end{document}
```

This appears to be the relevant section of the Thesis.cls file that deals with the abbreviations if it is of any help.

```
\newcommand\listsymbolname{Abbreviations}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofsymbols[2]{
\btypeout{\listsymbolname}
\addtotoc{\listsymbolname}
    \chapter*{\listsymbolname
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listsymbolname}{\MakeUppercase\listsymbolname}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
```

Comment: I don't think you should load `fncychap` if you have to stick with a given template.

Comment: @egreg There is no specific template that I have to use; just some certain guidelines to meet. Even these are not very specific. The `fncychap` package lets me adapt the template easily to the guidelines. To tell the truth I think I'm the only one in my department (history) that is using LaTeX for writing up my thesis. Supervisor only reviews my pdf output.

Comment: You could either call that *by design* or just add this to the list of very bad templates. The implementation is buggy as all of the templates on that site. You should inform the author and ask him to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to define a new environment based on the implementation of the `lof` and `lot`. It should be noted, that every thing in the class file is done *by hand*, there is no automation (helper macros) involved. That makes it very hard to maintain and leads to oddities (like the one you described).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{Thesis}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}
\makeatother


\makeatletter
\newenvironment{patchedlistofsymbols}[1]{%
    \begingroup%
    \singlespacing%
            \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}%
            \if@twocolumn%
            \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn%
            \else%
            \@restonecolfalse%
            \fi%
            \chapter*{\listsymbolname}%
            \addtotoc{\listsymbolname}%
\endgroup%  <- Note the difference
            \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listsymbolname}{\MakeUppercase\listsymbolname}%
                \begin{longtable}{#1}\ignorespaces
        }{\end{longtable}\cleardoublepage}%
\makeatother

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\tableofcontents
%\lhead{\emph{List of Figures}} 
\listoffigures 


%\lhead{\emph{Abbreviations}} 

%amend that to your needs

\begin{patchedlistofsymbols}{ll}
%\textbf{Acronym} & \textbf{W}hat (it) \textbf{S}tands \textbf{F}or \\
\textbf{UN} & \textbf{U}nited \textbf{N}ations \\ 
\textbf{UK} & The \textbf{U}nited \textbf{K}ingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland\\
\textbf{US} & The \textbf{U}nited \textbf{S}tates of America\\
\end{patchedlistofsymbols}
\chapter{Some real content}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,50}{\caption{caption \x}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

All those captions are just showing, that the list-commands mark the head on their own, no need for user interaction.

Comment: This is getting me somewhat there. Just two issues. 1. Now when I compile the Abbreviations page is not added to TOC and 2. If I change the line spacing it does it to the header as well as the table. Is there a way to set the line-spacing of the table independent of the header.

Comment: I simply missed the toc-entry. Just added it. I additionally restricted the singlespacing to the header, the actual list (a table) is set as the rest of the document *onehalfspaced*.